# WP is not loaded correctly when usingin external scripts

Tags: php, wordpress

i have problem with using function/events of WP in external file.

Here is a code example:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

define('THEME_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define ('WP_ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(THEME_ROOT))));

// Include WP
require( WP_ROOT . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

// Include Autoloader
require_once(THEME_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php');

function crazyLoaded() {
        echo 'Hello WP';
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'crazyLoaded');

$imagePost = media_handle_sideload(array('<siteroot>'.$data['Venue.image']),0);
```

Function crazyLoaded() is not calling at all and call media_handle_sideload() is leading to Fatal Error "Unknown Function" while wp_insert_post()/wp_insert_term() and other "wp_" functions are working correctly.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you try requiring `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`

Comment: This style of loading WP is almost never a good idea. Ever.  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: He tied wp-load.php as well.
What we are trying to do is build up some cron jobs that connects to 3rd party API and puts data into WP database. 

What style of requiring WP core is suitable?

Comment: @Fratyr Where this file is place?

Comment: In theme's root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
```

Saved the day.